# reload php page with javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have drawn a chess board in a php page. Every piece is set as draggable, and every tile as droppable. Once a piece is dropped on a tile, I'd like to reload the php page so the board can be drawn anew along with new positions. 
How can I do that: reloading the php page with javascript, without displaying a window asking for confirmation such as "To display this page, Firefox must send information that will repeat any action (such as a search or order confirmation) that was performed earlier.  ->Cancel; Resend" ?

Or perhaps there are better solutions?

Comment: Use GET instead of POST to send information to the server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to avoid having refresh reporting data (for any reason, including the user clicking the reload button) then use the POST-REDIRECT-GET pattern (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get). Read that, it will explain what to do.

Quick solution: you could try:

```
window.location.reload(true); //true sets request type to GET
```

**Use GET, instead of POST and the dialog box you are getting will go away.**

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. It does reload the php file. However the confirmation window still pops out. Also it seems my pieces take more time to appear on my board, whereas they appear in no time without javascript. Is it a normal thing?

Comment: Are you sure you are using GET instead of POST to send information to the server? It should only occur if you are using POST... And yeah it's normal. You gotta optimize your code :)

Comment: Yes thanks it is working now :) 
Though I think I will directly modify the DOM to move pieces in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Make use of

```
window.location.reload();
```

Answer (score 1):

will refresh automatically

```
<script>
    var timer = null;
    function auto_reload()
    {
        window.location = 'http://domain.com/page.php';  //your page location
    }

</script> 


<!-- Reload page every 10 seconds. -->
         <body onload="timer = setTimeout('auto_reload()',10000);">
```

reference http://davidwalsh.name/automatically-refresh-page-javascript-meta-tags